# Globally Declared DataTable Already Belongs to Another DataSet

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset

I am having problems understanding some logic but I am excited to learn what is goin on.  I have an application that uses a third party web service to execute xml and receive response back, no problems here.  I have some DataSets and DataTables that are declared globally.  The reason I have done this is because these DataSets and DataTables will not change but need to be accessed from other methods.  What happens is the form loads and my DataGridView populates just fine but when I select a different date from myComboBox the code throws an exception stating that the DataTable already belongs to another DataSet. Here is a simplified sample of what I am working with:

```
public class Test
{
  private BusinessLayer businessLayer;
  private int id;
  private List<int> employees;
  private DataSet employeeInfoDataSet;
  private DataSet employeesTimeDataSet;
  private DataTable employeeInfoDataTable;
  private DataTable employeesTimeDataTable;

  public Test()
  {
    businessLayer = new BusinessLayer();

    id = 3;

    // these should never change
    // I almost thought about making them static
    employees = businessLayer.getEmployees(id);
    employeeInfoDataSet = businessLayer.getEmployeeInfoDataSet(employees);
    employeeInfoDataTable = businessLayer.getEmployeeInfoDataTable(employeeInfoDataSet);
    employeeInfoDataTable.TableName = "EmployeeInfo";

    string date = myComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();

    initDataTable(date);
    bindDataGridView();
  }

  private void initDataTable(string date)
  {
    employeesTimeDataSet = businessLayer.getEmployeesTime(employees, date);
    employeesTimeDataSet.Tables.Add(employeeInfoDataTable); // <-- errors here
    employeesTimeDataTable = businessLayer.buildEmployeesTimeDataTable(employeesTimeDataSet);
  }

  private void bindDataGridView()
  {
    dgv.DataSource = timesheetsDataTable;
  }

  private void myComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string date = myComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
    initDataTable(date);
    bindDataGridView();
  }

}
```

I am struggling to understand why it runs fine when the form loads but throws this exception when I change the date. Can someone help me understand what is causing this?  Many, many thanks!

PS: The businessLayer.getEmployeeInfoDataTable and businessLayer.buildEmployeesTimeDataTable methods build the DataTables programmatically so there shouldn't be the "return ds.Tables[0]" issue where you need to use DataTable.Copy()...thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error-message is self-explanatory, isn't it? You are trying to add the same table to another `DataSet`  which you've already added to one in the constructor. You cannot add the same table(same reference) to two different `DataSets`. So what are you trying to do?

1. Maybe you want to check if it's already in a `DataSet`:

   ```
   if( employeeInfoDataTable.DataSet == null)
       employeesTimeDataSet.Tables.Add(employeeInfoDataTable);
   ```
2. Maybe you want to include this table into the `DataSet` in the first place which seems to be the best option if possible.
3. Or maybe you want to remove the table from the `DataSet` before you create it again. On this way the `DataSet` property of the table will be "cleared"(you cannot assign `null`) and you can add the table later to the newly created `DataSet`.

   So like this:

   ```
   private void initDataTable(string date)
   {
      employeesTimeDataSet.Tables.Remove(employeeInfoDataTable);
      employeesTimeDataSet = businessLayer.getEmployeesTime(employees, date);
      employeesTimeDataSet.Tables.Add(employeeInfoDataTable); // <-- now it works
      employeesTimeDataTable = businessLayer.buildEmployeesTimeDataTable(employeesTimeDataSet);
   }
   ```

Note that this exception is similar to the one that is raised if you're trying to add the same table twice to the same `DataSet`. Both is checked and not allowed.

Comment: It was my understanding that when employeesTimeDataSet = businessLayer.getEmployeesTime(employees, date); gets called the second time, the original or "old" employeesTimeDataSet gets collected or thrown away and replaced with a new one.  This led me to believe that the employeeInfoDataTable didn't belong to any DataSet at that point.  What I was trying to do is rebind the DataGridView when the user selects a different date from a combobox

Comment: @waltmagic: i must admit that i've first mistaken the reason myself.  You are not adding the same table twice to the same DataSet but to a different DataSet. That is also not allowed. `DataTableCollection.Add` checks if `table.DataSet` is `null`. If not it throws the exception. See my edit. By the way, [here's the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/DataTableCollection.cs#d986a85b78a19460#references).

Comment: OOOooh! I had the aww-haa moment I think.  Makes me feel kind of stupid now that I think about...it already belongs to the table doh! I need to rewrite my data layer methods to include the employee info I need.  I really appreciate the help.  Sometimes when I've been at the computer too long I loose IQ points or something.  Thanks a lot, seriously :)

Comment: @waltmagic: My pleasure! Note that i've edited my answer again.